# Updating wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

I am building a new website and I need to update it to the newest version. The steps are below could someone please explain in more detail whats involved in step 3? Thanks John

Follow the below steps to update the theme.

1) Download the theme from themeforest page.

2) If you have made any custom changes in the code, please take a backup of it.

3) Overwrite the updated theme files to the older theme files. Update the custom change

that you had already.

4) go to wp-content/plugins/ through FTP

5) Remove the folder designthemes-core-features/ from wp-content/plugins/

6) Then Login to Dashboard -> Appearance -> Install Plugins. Install the Designthemes Core

Features plugin. Thats it. Now you are updated to the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First part says to copy paste new theme files over old theme files.
2nd line means if you have changed (modified) any theme files of your current installation it needs to be made to new files (latest version you downloaded) manually. Or you might lose any changes or modifications you made.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply, all sorted now thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Before making any changes, it's crucial to back up your entire WordPress website. This includes both the files and the database. This ensures that you can revert to the previous state if anything goes wrong during the update.

As mentioned in step 1, download the latest version of the theme from the Themeforest page.

You can do this through various methods, such as FTP (File Transfer Protocol) or using the file manager provided by your hosting provider.

Navigate to the folder where your theme is installed. Typically, it's in the wp-content/themes/ directory.

Replace the old theme files with the new ones you downloaded. This includes files like style.css, functions.php, and other theme-specific files. Be cautious not to overwrite any custom files or directories where you might have made specific changes.

If you made any custom changes to the theme files, such as modifying the code in style.css or adding custom functions in functions.php, reapply those changes to the updated files. This step is crucial to ensure that your customizations are not lost.

If you are using a child theme, make sure to update its files as well.

After updating the theme, thoroughly test your website to ensure that everything is functioning correctly. Check different pages, functionalities, and any custom features you might have implemented.

By following these steps, you should successfully update your WordPress theme to the latest version while preserving any customizations you've made to the code.